# Binding TextField to Int property in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, data-binding

I have a stepper and a numeric entry in my XAML:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:brahms.View"
             x:Class="brahms.LabelRequestPage"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             Title="Request Labels"
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="True">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <views:IntConverter x:Key="IntToString"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="Number of labels:"/>
                <Entry Text="{Binding Path=LabelQuantity, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource IntToString}}" Keyboard="Numeric"/>
                <Stepper Value="{Binding LabelQuantity}" />
            </StackLayout>
            <Button Text="Cancel" Clicked="CancelButton_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And the associated property in code-behind calls `OnPropertyChanged`:

```
namespace brahms
{
    public partial class LabelRequestPage : ContentPage
    {
        private int _quantity;
        private int LabelQuantity
        {
            get
            {
                return _quantity;
            }
            set
            {
                _quantity = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LabelQuantity");
            }
        }

        public LabelRequestPage()
        {
            LabelQuantity = 1;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void CancelButton_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PopModalAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run my app the entry's default state is empty, not the value 1. The stepper doesn't change the entry, and setting the value in the entry doesn't change where the stepper is (if you count up clicks of + and - to work out what its current value is).

My conclusion is that the two controls aren't bound to the property in the code-behind, so my question is why not? What do I need to do to bind those controls to that property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this like that

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Label Text="Number of labels:"/>
            <Entry VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="{Binding LabelQuantity, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource IntToString}}" Keyboard="Numeric"/>
            <Stepper Value="{Binding LabelQuantity,Mode=TwoWay}" />
 </StackLayout>
```

Code behind should be like this.

```
public partial class LabelRequestPage : ContentPage
{
    public LabelRequestPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
        LabelQuantity = 1;
    }

    private int _quantity;
    public int LabelQuantity
    {
        get
        {
            return _quantity;
        }
        set
        {
            _quantity = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LabelQuantity));
        }
    }
}
```

And for converter you can use this.

```
public class IntConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is int)
            return ((int)value).ToString();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int number = 0;
        int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out number);
        return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works, initially it didn't but I didn't notice you change the property visibility from `private` to `public` on `LabelQuantity`. Why is that needed? The XAML implements part of the same class as the code-behind, why can't it access the private properties?

Comment: You cannot access private properties from BindingContext because it is the instance of the page so you cannot access the private properties from instance.